# Call a function from js file in Robot Framework

Tags: javascript, selenium, automated-tests, robotframework

There is a possibility to execute javascript from file.

```
Execute JavaScript    ${CURDIR}/js_to_execute.js
```

But how can I call a function by name from this file?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to call a function using `Execute Javascript` out of the box. But it's possible to pass a function name as an argument.

```
Execute Javascript    ${CURDIR}/js/utils.js    ARGUMENTS    clickElement    ${locator}
```

The content of `utils.js` file:

```
var utils = utils || {};

(function (arguments) {
    utils.clickElement = function (locator) {
        // implementation of the function
    }

    // this piece of code does the trick
    // get function name from arguments and remove it from the list of arguments
    var functionName = [].shift.call(arguments);     
    // call the function and pass the arguments
    utils[functionName].apply(this, arguments);
})(arguments);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will be little ugly but it works. You need to inject your whole Javascript code using Execute Javascript first and than you will be able to call the function you injected.

You can inject Javascript using below javascript code on google home page,

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.text = "document.getElementById('hplogo').addEventListener('click',function(){alert('Google');});";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
```

In robotframework you can do the same using **Execute Javascript**

```
Open Browser    https://www.google.com
Wait Until Page Contains Element    id=hplogo
Execute Javascript    var s = document.createElement('script');s.text = "document.body.addEventListener('click',function(){alert('Google')})";document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
Sleep    2s          #wait so that injected javascript gets evaluated 
Execute Javascript    document.getElementById('hplogo').click();
Sleep    10s    #wait and click anywhere on body of the page to see the alert
```

Your `s.text` variable will have whole javascript code from js file in one line. Of course if your javascript is long than it will be dirty work but in one of the site I had to do this for pdf export and it is working fine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I meant a bit different thing. I wasn't clear enough, I meant to call one of the functions from a file by name.

Comment: The problem is from your local machine you can not inject a js file into the browser page, but what you can do is inject whole javascript as a code. Now above example does the same thing where you need to inject whole javascript code or the specific function as shown above, than you will be able to call it afterwards using Execute Javascript function.

Comment: Updated the answer to show how you can call the injected function.